# Angularjs with subdomain wildcards (best way)

Tags: angularjs, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain, route-provider

guys.How is it going? I am having a hard time trying to figure out some stuff here. No success so far. The thing is...

How does Angularjs work with subdomain wildcards?

Since I can't inject location service in the app.config, I needed some way to track the url I am accessing in every request, without having to check when every single angularjs controller is loaded, using $routeProvider and locationProvider

*** UPDATE ***

I have a domain for a Rails 4 application(as an API), and I am using angularjs to render the views and everything else. For the app, I will have a subdomain for a specific purpose. But users will only be able to access the subdomain after logged in, and this will create a subsubdomain for them. So, I need to do something like this:

- http://domain.com (rendering the regular app)
- http://subdomain.domain.com (only to log in)
- http://user1.subdomain.domain.com
- http://user2.subdomain.domain.com (both rendering something completely different from the regular app rendering)

All this using routeParams. I used angular-devise to login.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: your question isn't very clear.  Why would angular have issues with subdomains? and why can't you inject $location?

Comment: I don't understand either... not hard to check the domain and subdomain using `window.location` object anywhere in the app...including config or run and setting your base url from there for the whole app. You aren't excluded from accessing the window properties just because your code is in angular components. The window is still in scope

Comment: Beyond that ...what specific problem are you trying to solve? Question is really vague

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I tried to elaborate the question a little bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is trying to figure out the same thing, here is what I did:

1. In the routes.rb file, I pointed routes with subdomains to a rails controller:

> get '', to: 'controller#action', constraints: { subdomain: /.+/ }

2. I created to angular modules. One for the regular app, and the other for to the app with the subdomain
3. In the application.html.erb file, I make the ng-app dynamic, so angular will be able to know which app I am talking about. angular_app returns the string to one of the angular_modules:

> ng-app="<%= angular_app %>"

After that, angularjs routeParams is in charge to render the app.

Thank was it.